# Generate a parser from programatically generated BNF

Tags: parsing, haskell

I've seen two approaches to parsing:

1. Use a parser generator like [`happy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/happy). This allows you to specify your language in BNF, and not worry about the intricacies of parsing. However, since it's a preprocessor you have to write your whole parse tree textually.
2. Use a parser directly like [`megaparsec`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec). With this approach you have direct access to your code so you can generate your parser programatically, but you haven't got the convenience of happy's simple BNF specification with precedence annotations etc. Also it seems non trivial to print out a BNF tree for documentation from your parsing code unless this is considered during it's construction.

What I'd like to do is something like this:

1. Generate a data structure programatically that represents BNF.
2. Feed this through to a "happy like" parser generator to generate a parser.
3. Feed this through a pretty printer to generate actual BNF documentation.

The reason I want to do this is that the grammar I'm working on has grown quite large and has a lot of repetition, as a lot of it's constructs are similar to others but slightly different. It would improve maintenence effort if it could be generated programmatically instead of modifying happy BNF spec directly, but I'd rather not have to develop my own parser from scratch.

Any ideas about a good approach here. It would be great if I could just generate a data structure and force it into `happy` (as it presumably generates it's own internal structure after parsing the BNF feed to it) but `happy` doesn't seem to have a library interface.

I guess I could generate attonated BNF, and feed that through to happy, but it seems like a messy process of converting back and forth. A cleaner approach would be better. Perhaps even a BNF style extension to `parsec` or `megaparsec`?

Comment: So why can't you 1) generate a data structure that represents your BNF [I assume you dont have trouble here], 2) pretty print that to produce happy BNF spec text 3) feed that to happy?

Comment: For constructs that are very similar to each other, you may be interested in Happy's parametrized productions.

Comment: You may be interested in [`BNFC-meta`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/BNFC-meta-0.4.0.3), which is slightly more general in that it provides a metaprogram (in the form of TH) which converts a representation of a grammer to a meta-representation of a parser, which of course you can convert to an actual parser by just splicing that in. 1 is `read::String->Grammar` and 2 is `ebnf::Grammar->DecsQ` (I'm not sure what you mean by 3 - what is "BNF documentation"?)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do would to make some data type representing the relevant grammar, and then convert it to a parser using some parser combinators as a (run-time) "compile" step.  Unfortunately, most parser combinators are less efficient and/or less flexible (in some ways) than the parser generators, so this would be a bit of a lowest common denominator approach.  That said, the [grammar-combinators](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/grammar-combinators) library may be useful, though it doesn't appear to be maintained.

There are libraries that can generate parsers at run-time.  One I found just now is [Grempa](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Grempa-0.2.2/docs/Data-Parser-Grempa-Dynamic.html), which doesn't appear to be maintained but that may not be a problem.  Another option (by the same person who made Grempa but maintained) is [Earley](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Earley) which, due to the way Earley parsers are made, it makes sense to have an explicit grammar that gets processed into a parser.  Earley parsing is certainly flexible, but may be overpowered for you (or maybe not).